# Iterating all Values of self.request.arguments

Tags: python, tornado

Is there an easy way to access all of the values from a post in tornado without having to specify the argument for each one? At the moment just printing them to screen.

I can iterate through RequestHandler.request.arguments like this:

```
for f in self.request.arguments:
        details += "<hr/>" + f
```

And I can return an individual value like:

```
RequestHandler.get_argument("ArgumentName", default=None, strip=False)
```

But how do I dynamically return all of the values sent through a form?

Do I have to call `get_argument` for each one like this?

```
    for f in self.request.arguments:
        details += "<hr/>" + self.get_argument(f, default=None, strip=False)
```

This is what the RequestHandler looks like at the moment:

```
class Sent(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        details = ""
        for f in self.request.arguments:
            details += "<hr/>" + self.get_argument(f, default=None, strip=False)
        self.write(details)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arguments` it's actually a dictionary (and that's why iterating over it gives you only its keys) so you can use `values()` method:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import textwrap
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web

from tornado.options import define, options
define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)

class TestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        details = ""
        for f in self.request.arguments.values():
            details += "<hr/>" + ", ".join(f)
        self.write(details)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()

    app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r"/", TestHandler)])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I also use `join()` method because values of that dictionary are lists.